# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, identityserver4

I have a simple web api project, which looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
        [Route("Get")]
        public ActionResult<string> SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

I am trying to test it with Postman.  By following the steps here: https://kevinchalet.com/2016/07/13/creating-your-own-openid-connect-server-with-asos-testing-your-authorization-server-with-postman/

1) Send the request below and receive a token as expected:

[image]

2) Attempt to send another request with the authorization token as shown below:

[image]

Why do I get a 401 (unauthorized) error? The WWW-Authenticate response header says: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer is invalid".  I am using .Net Core 3.1.  I have commented out the sensitive information in the screenshots.

The web api works as expected when accessed from an MVC application.

Here is the startup code:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = identityUrl; //identityurl is a config item
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = apiName;

                });
```

Comment: The access token is in the certificate.  It is failing.  The security mode is TLS/SSL which has a number of different options like 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit.  I've seen many people when upgrading to Net 4.7 the security was failing.  I suspect the same is also happening with Core 3.1.  So the token you are using and the mode set in the c# code aren't the same.  You may want to see the wiki article to get better understanding : https://www.google.com/search?q=wiki+tls&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS752US753&oq=wiki+tls&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3030j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: How do I find the mode in the C# code? Thanks.

Comment: I have added some C# code to the bottom of the question.  Please take a look?

Comment: Good question.  I have not gotten any real feedback from people on how this issue was fixed.  I suspect it has to do with the Certificate2 class and the compiling mode x64 or x86.  It seems like it broke when microsoft released Net 4.7.  Since Core 3.1 is also new I suspect the same issue in Core3.1  You could try targeting to older version of Net or the compiler options.

Comment: @jdweng, I have tested this on the app as a .net core 2.1 app and a .net core 2.2 app.  The same problem occurs.  Therefore it is not related to .net core 3.1.  Do you have any other suggestions? Please bear in mind that I am new to Postman so the solution may be simpler than you expect.  Thanks.

Comment: `The issuer is invalid` is most likely something wrong with your `options.Authority = identityUrl`

Comment: what is the authority , it should be base-address of your identityserver

Comment: @Nan Yu, thanks.  It was because I was specifying localhost in Postman and the base-address is the IP address of my PC.  Changing the address to the IP address resolved my issue.  If you would like to post an answer then I will give some credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Authority` of `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` middleware should be the base-address of your identityserver , middleware will contact the identity server's OIDC metadata endpoint to get the public keys to validate the JWT token .

Please confirm that the Authority is the url of identity server where you issued the jwt token .

Comment: For me a similar issue was the case. 
My application had configured https://baseadress with a / at the end . This was validated against the oidc issuer without the slash.

Comment: @RazorShorts you save my day. I was not using / when configuring the issuer. Don't know why this work like this

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar issue. I was generating my token via Postman when sending in my request and using an external IP to access my Keycloak instance running inside of my kubernetes cluster. When my service inside the cluster tried to verify the token against the authority, it failed because the internal service name (http://keycloak) it used to validated the token was different than what Postman had used to generate the token (<external-keycloak-ip).

Since this was just for testing, I set the `ValidateIssuer` to false.

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = false 
};
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, but added the issuer to my list of valid issuers to get past the problem, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306175/bearer-error-invalid-token-error-description-the-issuer-is-invalid/66664653#66664653

Answer (score 5):

I'm on dotnet 5.0, adding swagger (NSwag.AspNetCore) to my AzureAD "protected" web api and got a similar error about invalid issuer:

```
 date: Tue,16 Mar 2021 22:50:58 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/<your-tenant-id>/' is invalid" 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

So, instead of not validating the issuer, I just added sts.windows.net to the list (important parts in the end):

```
// Enable JWT Bearer Authentication
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    // Authority will be Your AzureAd Instance and Tenant Id
    options.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/v2.0";

    // The valid audiences are both the Client ID(options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[]
    {
        Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"], $"api://{Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]}",

    };
    // Valid issuers here:
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[]
    {
        $"https://sts.windows.net/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/",
        $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/"
    };
});
```

This solved my problems. Now, why NSwag uses sts.windows.net as token issuer, I don't know. Seems wrong. I'm using these package versions:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.10.8" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting `ValidateIssuer = false` like @nedstark179 proposes will work but it will also remove a security validation.

If you use a ASP.NET Core template with Individual Accounts (IdentityServer) and receive this error:

`WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://example.com' is invalid"`

It is probably related to this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28880

For example a new Blazor Webassembly App with Individual Accounts and ASP.NET Core hosted from Visual Studio.

[image]

.NET 6.0 Known Issues only mentions it could happen in development but it can happen in production hosted as an Azure App Service as well.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#spa-template-issues-with-individual-authentication-when-running-in-development

I created an issue about that here:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42072

The example fix for development was not enough.

Started of by adding a new Application settings for the Azure App Service called `IdentityServer:IssuerUri` with value `https://example.com/`. This can of course be placed in `appsettings.json` as well.  I then added the code below:

```
//Used until https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42072 is fixed
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.IdentityServer.IssuerUri))
{
    builder.Services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme, o => o.Authority = settings.IdentityServer.IssuerUri);
}
```

below this code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

I have not verified if it matters where the code is placed but `AddIdentityServerJwt()` calls `AddPolicyScheme` and `.AddJwtBearer(IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme, null, o => { });`. Therefore I deemed it appropriate to set it after this code has been called.

After doing this the app still failed with the same error. I then modified `AddIdentityServer` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    //Used until https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42072 is fixed
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.IdentityServer.IssuerUri))
                    {
                        options.IssuerUri = settings.IdentityServer.IssuerUri;
                    }
                })
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and then it started working for me. If you still experience a problem you could also try to set `AuthenticatorIssuer` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    //Used until https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42072 is fixed
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.IdentityServer.IssuerUri))
    {
        options.Tokens.AuthenticatorIssuer = settings.IdentityServer.IssuerUri;
    }
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Same exact scenario.

Comment: Man, I'm hitting this right now and it's killing me. For some reason, on the deployed app when I log in through multiple browsers (say on my phone and one open on a laptop), one browser connection gets a 401 accessing my protected apis and another one goes through just fine. And I'm 'logged in' on both. It's killing me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, simply adding /v2.0 to the Authority was sufficient.

Case:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x => {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Audience = "client id here";
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id here/v2.0";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case(.net 8) I had to add `ValidIssuer = issuer,` to the `AddJwtBearer()` within Program.cs, piece of code below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = issuer,
        ValidAudience = audience,
        ValidateAudience = true
    };
});
```