Bearer error. Token is invalid. Possible docker-compse setup issue?
I have seen this question asked before, but none of the answers have resolved my issue or helped me understand what the issue actually is.
So I would be grateful for any help. As mentioned in the title, I am getting the following error when I try to reach an authorized endpoint:

www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The issuer 'BookyWooks' is invalid".

I believe my issue is to do with docker so I will show my docker-compose files and my code setup:
First my docker-compose.override.yml:
bookywooks.catalogue.api:
  container_name: bookywooks.catalogue.api
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - "ConnectionStrings__Database=Server=postgresdb;Database=CatalogueDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"
    - IdentityServerURL=http://bookywooks.identityserver
    - RabbitMQConfiguration__Config__HostName=${BOOKYWOOKS_RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME:-rabbitmq}
    - RabbitMQConfiguration__Config__UserName=${BOOKYWOOKS_RABBITMQ_USERNAME:-guest}
    - RabbitMQConfiguration__Config__Password=${BOOKYWOOKS_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD:-guest}
    - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
    - Jaeger__Protocol=http
    - Jaeger__Port=4317
    - Jaeger__Host=jaeger
  ports:
    - "5007:8080"
    - "5009:8081"
  volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
    - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro



bookywooks.identityserver:
    container_name: bookywooks.identityserver
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
      - "ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=identityserverdb;Database=IdentityServerDb;User=sa;Password=Your_password123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
    ports:
      - "5011:8080"
      - "5015:8081"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro

networks:
  booky_wooks_network:
    external: true

Then my docker-compose.yml:
bookywooks.catalogue.api:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bookywookscatalogueapi
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: BookyWooks.Catalogue.Api/Dockerfile
  depends_on:
    - postgresdb
    - rabbitmq
    - jaeger
    # - otel-collector
  networks:
    - booky_wooks_network

identityserverdb:
  container_name: booky_wooks_identityserverdb
  image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
  environment:
    - "SA_PASSWORD=Your_password123"
    - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "5435:1433"
  networks:
    - booky_wooks_network



bookywooks.identityserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bookywooksidentityserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: BookyWooks.IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - booky_wooks_network

networks:
  booky_wooks_network:
    external: true

Here is my IdentityServer setup:
    internal static class HostingExtensions
    {
        public static WebApplication ConfigureServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    
            builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    
            builder.Services
                .AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    
                    // see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/resources/
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                    options.IssuerUri = "BookyWooks";
                })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
    
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    
                    // register your IdentityServer with Google at https://console.developers.google.com
                    // enable the Google+ API
                    // set the redirect URI to https://localhost:5001/signin-google
                    options.ClientId = "copy client ID from Google here";
                    options.ClientSecret = "copy client secret from Google here";
                });
    
            return builder.Build();
        }
    
        public static WebApplication ConfigurePipeline(this WebApplication app)
        {
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
    
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
    
            app.MapRazorPages()
                .RequireAuthorization();
    
            return app;
        }
    }

Here is my BookCatalogue setup:
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Host.UseSerilog(SeriLogger.Configure);
        // Add services to the container.
        var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
        builder.Services.AddMediatR(config =>
        {
            config.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly);
        });
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        
        
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Book Catalogue Microservice", Version = "v1" });
            // To Enable authorization using Swagger (JWT)    
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your valid token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9\"",
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement { { new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" } }, Array.Empty<string>() } });
        
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
        
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                   .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                   {
                       var identityServerUrl = builder.Configuration["IdentityServerURL"];
                       options.Authority = identityServerUrl;
                       options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                       {
                           ValidateAudience = false
                       };
                   });
        builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
        //builder.Services.AddMarten(opts =>
        //{
        //    opts.Connection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")!);
        //}).UseLightweightSessions();
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<CatalogueDbContext>(x =>
        {
            x.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")!, opt =>
            {
                var x = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");
                opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(5);
            });
        });
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IMassTransitService, CatalogueMassTransitService>();
        //if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        //builder.Services.InitializeMartenWith<CatalogueInitialData>();
        
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddMessageBroker<CatalogueDbContext>(builder.Configuration, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), false);
        builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(builder.Configuration);
        builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryMetrics(builder.Configuration);
        var app = builder.Build();
        
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseSwagger();
            //app.UseSwaggerUI();
            await app.InitialiseDatabaseAsync();
        }
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Book Catalogue Microservice"));
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        
        app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();

Here is my BookCatalogue controller:
     [ApiController]
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     public class BookCatalogueController : ControllerBase
     {
         private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
         {
             "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
         };
    
         private readonly ILogger<BookCatalogueController> _logger;
    
         public BookCatalogueController(ILogger<BookCatalogueController> logger)
         {
             _logger = logger;
         }
    
         [Authorize]
         [HttpGet("products")]
         public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
         {
             return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new Product
             {
                 Id = new Guid("1e9c1a7e-1d9b-4c0e-8a15-5e12b5f5ad34"),
                 Name = "To Kill a Mockingbird",
                 Description = "A novel about the serious issues of rape and racial inequality, told through the eyes of a young girl.",
                 ImageFile = "to-kill-a-mockingbird.png",
                 Price = 10.99M,
                 Category = new List<string> { "Fiction" },
                 Quantity = 10
             }).ToArray();
         }
    
         [HttpGet("products/test")]
         public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsTest()
         {
             return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new Product
             {
                 Id = new Guid("1e9c1a7e-1d9b-4c0e-8a15-5e12b5f5ad34"),
                 Name = "To Kill a Mockingbird",
                 Description = "A novel about the serious issues of rape and racial inequality, told through the eyes of a young girl.",
                 ImageFile = "to-kill-a-mockingbird.png",
                 Price = 10.99M,
                 Category = new List<string> { "Fiction" },
                 Quantity = 10
             }).ToArray();
         }
     }
```csharp

Here is how I generate a token:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is that token enccoded in jwt.io:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is me using swagger to authorize:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

And here is the error:
[![enter image description here][4]][4]


This question was asked here: 
[Stackoverflow bearer error][5]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/AJLWPd58.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/3LAs4QlD.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/xVvEJnli.png
  [4]: https://i.sstatic.net/fzhBz486.png
  [5]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306175/bearer-error-invalid-token-error-description-the-issuer-is-invalid
However I do not believe it was actually resolved and if so I have failed to understand the answer. Can anyone please help? 

